# spring apache camel from spring bean

Tags: spring, apache-camel

Java - spring - camel

I want to initiate the camel route with list of services.

want to do some thing as following but `from` method seems to be is not a producer. how can i define dynamic producer ?

```
    @Component
    class A{

    List getServices(){
      return services;
     }
    }

    @Component
    class B{

      void save(List services){
        save(services)
      }
    }

    class myRoute extends SpringRouteBuilder{
    ...

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception{

     from("A", "getServices").to("direct:my-route-b");
     from("direct:my-route-b").to("b", "save");


    }
   ...
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject a producerTemplate in A and send the services to direct:my-route-b as described [here](https://camel.apache.org/pojo-producing.html).

```
@Component
class A{

    @EndpointInject(uri="direct:my-route-b")
    ProducerTemplate producer;

    List getServices(){
      return services;
    }

   public void invoke() { 
      producer.sendBody(getServices());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Autowire A a; a.invoke(); // this is how we trigger it correct ?